# Does Spring MVC has something like CancellationToken?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, servlets

HTTP request could be aborted on front-end at any time. At the moment I observe that my `Spring` application does not have a clue about this fact until I start writing the response to the wire. At the same time knowing that the request was aborted beforehand I could stop doing useless job by supporting cooperative cancellation.

`ASP.NET` has an implementation of request cancellation based on `CancellationToken`. I am looking for something similar for `Spring` but cannot find anything. I understand that `CancellationToken` gets particulary useful with `async/await` pattern but even without `async/await` it could have been useful.

So two questions:

1. Does `Spring MVC` have this featre?
2. If not, how its absence is typically worked-around? Of course, I could add another REST endpoint to notify the back-end that the request was cancelled, but this is a bit awkward. It's like re-inventing the concept that is already supported on protocol level.

And two bonus questions (in case the answer to Q1 is `No`):

3. Does `Spring` team have plans for supporting it?
4. Did they ever give any comments why this was not supported?

Thanks.

Comment: This isn't something Spring MVC would provide. The Servlet container would. Why do you need this?

Comment: Thanks for feedback. I need this because in my case back-end is doing some heavy processing which I would like to cancel as soon I the request is cancelled by the user. To be more precise I am doing a quite long query to DB (could be 2 min). If the user goes to the next page, another query would be started. Keeping request thread for 2 minutes, making DB doing some complicated queries when the result is no longer needed is just squandering.

Comment: I don't know how IIS does this, but like the duplicate explains you have to attempt to write to get feedback about whether the client disconnected. This is not an easy problem to solve. The Servlet API doesn't expose anything directly to detect that.